# HTML file input not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, input

I'm making a social media website for a project. I have a PHP function that allows the user to upload an image to a post and inside the function is an html form to allow them to select a form.

```
echo "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
            echo "<input type='file' name='myFile'/>";
            echo "<label for='myFile' id='fileLabel'>File input</label>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submitFileForm' value='Upload' />";
echo "</form>";
```

When I process the form with this code and `print_r($_FILES)` is empty but if I `echo $_POST['myFile']` it displays the correct file name.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitFileForm'])) {

print_r($_FILES);
$my_folder = "img/";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], $my_folder . $_FILES['myFile']['name'])) {
    echo 'Received file' . $_FILES['myFile']['name'] . ' with size ' . $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
} else {
    echo 'Upload failed!';

    var_dump($_FILES['myFile']['error']);
}
}
```

Thank you for the help , I have been trying to debug this for the last 2 hours. Also I forgot to mention, I already tried increasing `upload_max_filesize = 100M` and `input_max_size = 100M` and that is not the problem.

Comment: Your script runs fine for me. Does your ini file have `file_uploads = On`? Also did you see if `post_max_size` was set higher?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the if condition as following

```
if (isset($_POST['submitFileForm'])) {
```

It will be working

Comment: sorry thats actually what I had but I coppied code from an earlier version in this post. Its updated now